# How to answer this query in sql?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table like follow:

[image: my table]

I want to select items that it's active column is 1 and all children recursively.
result will be like follow:

```
a,b,c,d
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the options for storing hierarchical data in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database). To be honest your schema sucks and the query will be extremely inefficient. Especially with high number of descendants.

Comment: MySQL version??

Comment: MySql version is: 5.7

Comment: If you upgrade to MySQL-8.0 you have recursive CTE which make this quite easy. What happens to the output where there is more than one child?

Comment: all of children will be as result.

Comment: no answer :-( ?